# Cannot install Ubunt 14.04.3 LTS frpm USB or CD

Tags: boot

Did make a new partition 350G and formatted it in Ext4.
The LIVE USB with Ubuntu 14.04.3LTS is running, however,
installing is not possible!!
Who can me explain in simple staps what to do please??
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I also got this in my New Hp Lap.

So what I do is,

1. In choose menu(installing Path selector), Go to **Something Else**
2. And remove your ext partition (using `-` left side bottom of screen) and make different partion for
   **SWAP**
3. and then create your disk with your values
4. then select all your drives and click install

> **Note :** This will install in largest partion which you create.
>   And I just did that

(Image from google)
[image]

after **something else** Screen

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much indeed for your answer. But how can you create sda1, sda2 etc and the name of the system behind?

Comment: you mean new partition??

Comment: Ok Addulla, Ubuntu is working more ore less. Some things do not work, like dconf-editor etc.

Comment: If tht is system file you need permition to do that